# How to write itertools product more elegantly

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need a lot of nested loops and want to use itertool's product. The following does what I want:

```
for v9,v8,v7,v6,v5,v4,v3,v2,v1 in itertools.product([0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]):
    #do something with v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9
```

However, it is far from elegant. Is there a way to write it in a neater way? It would be nice to "outsource" the arguments of the itertools.product in some way such that one can adapt it better. I mean something like

```
lim = 10
var = [f"v{i}" for i in range(1,lim)]
kar = [[0,1] for _ in range(1,lim)]
for var in itertools.product(kar): 
    #do something
```

I'm fully aware that this cannot work in various dimensions, I just wrote it to make clear what I have in mind.

Comment: `for v in itertools.product(...): for x in v: ...`…?!

Comment: What do you _want_ to do with `v*`?

Comment: If your use case is just a list of one and zeros, you could do `for var in range(1 << 9)` and play with each bit.

Comment: Did you have a quick look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)? There is the `repeat` argument so at least you could simplify to `for ... in product([0, 1], repeat=n)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks a lot! This solves the issue. Tbh I'm wondering why I struggled so much with it - the solution is very easy...

Comment: ***Always*** check the docs... It has a lot of useful information. Also, someone bothered to write it - it would be a shame not to use it :)

Answer (score -1):

You can acces your variables using indexes:

```
lim = 10
var = [f"v{i}" for i in range(1,lim)]
kar = [[0,1] for _ in range(1,lim)]

for var in itertools.product(*kar): 

    print(f"v1 = {var[-1]}")
    print(f"v2 = {var[-2]}")
    print(f"v3 = {var[-3]}")
    print(f"v4 = {var[-4]}")
    print(f"v5 = {var[-5]}")
    print(f"v6 = {var[-6]}")
    print(f"v7 = {var[-7]}")
    print(f"v8 = {var[-8]}")
    print(f"v9 = {var[-9]}")
```

This solution is robust with dimensions.